# Regex to find text between string pattren

Tags: java, regex

***String:*** `[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]`

***Result I Want:*** `[img border=0]images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]` without `/scm/` text.

***Issue:*** Text `scm` is not static, could be any other text in data.

***What I want:***  Have a look to this string 
`[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]` 
Regex which can fetch a text between `]` and `images/bbcode/` so the regex will detect the `\scm\` text and then can remove this `\scm\` from String data and end result will look like
`[img border=0]images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]`

PS: I am implementing this logic in `Java`.

Comment: Yeah, where's your code so far?

Comment: is `[img border=0]` static?

Comment: Is `images/bbcode/` static?

Comment: @MajidRoustaei yes this is static

Comment: @DavidDr90  `images/bbcode/` is also static

Comment: So you want to remove all the text between `[img border=0]` and `images/bbcode/`, correct?

Comment: @Abra yes we can say remove any test between `[img border=0]` and `images/bbcode/`

Comment: I want a generic solution around this problem

Comment: Thanks guys for the ansers, Now I will implement this in my code and see what will be the best perfomance solution can be used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have captured text between '] and /images..' and replace this text with "". Check the following  demo:

```
String s = "[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]";
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=])/[^/]+/","");
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can reach the goal without using regex, too.

since you said that the other parts are static, try this:

```
String myStr = "[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]";
myStr = "[img border=0]" + myStr.substring(myStr.indexOf("images"));
System.out.println(myStr);
```

and the output will be:

```
[img border=0]images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]
```

Comment: Doesn't the question ask for a _regular expression_, which I don't think your answer provides. Or maybe you should mention that a _regex_ is not required in order to solve the problem?

Comment: To make this answer more generic use: `myStr = "[img border=0]" + myStr.substring(myStr.indexOf("/", myStr.indexOf("/") + 1) + 1);`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback guys . @Abra, @DavidDr90.

your command causes a small bug where there be a `/` in the dynamic part.

Answer (score 1):

if `[img border=0]` dynamic, you can take all except `/scm/`

[some demo](https://regex101.com/r/24x7Kz/2)

```
   String input = "[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^.*\\])\\/.*?\\/(.*$)");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        String output = m.replaceFirst("$1$2"); 
        System.out.println(output);
    }



 // -> [img border=0]images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way to solve this same problem

```
String pattereString = "].*/images";

        String maineString = "[img border=0]/scm/images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]";
        maineString = maineString.replaceAll(pattereString, "images");
        System.out.println(maineString);
```

Output:

```
[img border=0]images/bbcode/sets/misc/bullet_go.png[/img]
```